# Creating fade-in drop-down navbar buttons with CSS3

Tags: html, css, navbar

Going to edit this, since I'm a stubborn idiot who has seen the error of his way. More or less the same question about how to create a drop-down group of links on a horizontal navbar, but this time, with the usage of ul and li.

So far, I've made this much progress:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="width">
        <li><a ...</li>
        <li><a ...
            <ul>
                <li><a ...</li>
                <li><a ...</li>
                <li><a ...</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a ...</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul{width:100%;text-align:justify;font-size:0;}
nav ul:after{content:"";width:100%;display:inline-block;}
nav li{list-style:none;display:inline-block;}
nav a{display:inline-block;padding:10px;}
nav ul ul{display:none;}
```

However, it's still incomplete, as I'm unsure how to progress from here. Currently this code hides the content that would appear in the drop down menu, but there is no code to make it visible again. Guides I've seen make use of floats. Are those absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 2):

You will still need to wrap the drop down link with its subordinate links.  Like this:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="bg">
    <div class="navwrap width">
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#">Link1</a>
            <div class='dropdown'>
                <a href="#">Link2</a>
                <div class='droplinks'>
                    <a href='#'>Drop Link 1</a>
                    <a href='#'>Drop Link 1</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="dropdown2">Link3</a>
            <a href="#">Link4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**New CSS:**

```
.dropdown{
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.dropdown a {
    width: 100%;
}
.droplinks{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    height:0;
    transition: height 0.2s linear;
}
.dropdown a:hover ~ .droplinks{
    display:block;
    height: 150px;
}
.droplinks:hover {
    display:block;
    height: 150px;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsaat14/usf8T/14/).  This is just a rough example, you will need to adjust some alignment and stuff like that, but I think you can do that.   It was mainly to show you how the drop down action worked.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot sometime tomorrow and let you know how it goes. I should be able to get the alignment done as well.

Comment: Alright, it sort of works. I had to remove the width and float from .dropdown, the width from .dropdown a, and the height from .dropdown a:hover ~..., since it wasn't doing anything. I also had to change the .dropdown display to inline-block to get everything aligned the way it should be. However, the drop-down transition doesn't work. Even so, I don't suppose you know if it's possible to use a fade-in, instead of a slide, do you?

Comment: Sure you can fade it in.  Just animate the opacity.

Comment: You mean replace the transition:height with transition:opacity? Either way, something is still blocking it from working. I got it to work momentarily, and then it stopped working again. I need to mess around with the code to see what's stopping it.

Comment: @Hiigaran Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: I've decided that listed navbars are a better idea, so I'm now going with that, and edited my question accordingly. I should still be able to use most of what you've suggested though.